# Как выставить у всех элементов списка значение?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<Button> btn = new List<Button>();
btn.Add(BtnVersion);
btn.Add(BtnLogErrors);
btn.Add(BtnLogClear);
```

как выставить у всех сразу параметр `IsEnabled = false`

Comment: btn.ForEach(x => x.isEnabled = false);

Comment: по идее, можно пройтись циклом и выставить false, мб есть способ более оптимальный

Comment: @Sublihim: Хм, а чем это отличается от `foreach (var x in btn) x.isEnabled = false;` (кроме ненужного создания лямбды)?

Comment: @Sublihim то что надо... Сделай как ответ, я его зачту

Comment: @VladD он же просил linq :)

Comment: @VladD эта лямбда ф-ция не усложняет чтение и уменьшает код

Comment: @Sublihim: Это не LINQ. `ForEach` в LINQ нет.

Comment: @KtoTo: Она не уменьшает код, посчитайте сами.

Comment: @VladD значит я интуитивно понял, что они имеет ввиду

Comment: @Sublihim: Автор просит сделать плохо. Не надо идти на поводу у автора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя лямбду:

```
btn.ForEach(x => x.IsEnabled = false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте

```
foreach(var button in btn)
{
    button.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Вот это правильный ответ.

Comment: @VladD почему ответ с лямбда не является верным ? вы явно сделали акцент на этот ответ

Comment: @Lolidze: Код с лямбдой ничем не лучше этого. Он не короче и не яснее, это просто то же, что и с `foreach`, но в переставленном порядке. Наоборот, он хуже, потому что создаёт лишнюю лямбду (в которой вы, например, не можете использовать `ref`-аргументы процедуры). Вот статья Эрика Липперта про это: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: @VladD кстати он сам пометил этот вопрос, как философский и не все в комментариях были согласны с его утверждением о вреде использования ForEach

Comment: @Sublihim: Тем не менее. `ForEach` никогда не лучше, чем `foreach`. По выразительности код получается хуже, и ещё и его [не всегда можно использовать](https://ideone.com/TZbm4U).